# JQuery datepicker return weeknumber and day of week

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Im trying to get the weeknumber and the name/shortcut of the weekday according to the chosen date through a JQuery calendar.
Im not really proficient in JQuery so i can get the weeknumber, but i cant seem to get the name of the day with it.

Could anyone help me out?

```
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $('#weekNumber').val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to get the date, than extract the name of the day from it:

```
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      alert($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', date));
```

hope it helps!

edit: you can find the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4smc1dbj/).

Answer (score 3):

You can add in your existing block to grab the day name, by using the format date syntax, found in the datepicker documentation, here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

In this case, full day name is obtained from 'DD', so your updated code might look like:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        var d = new Date(dateText);
        $('#weekNumber').val($.datepicker.iso8601Week(d));
        $('#dayName').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD', d));
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/zL6m2wck/

Answer (score 1):

Here is alot of information on how to use the javascript Date object.

Here is the code I suggest you:

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            onSelect: function( dateText, dateObj ){
            //You can get your date string that way
            console.log(dateText);

            //You can get a few value about the date, look in your console to see what you can do with that object
            //i.e. - console.log(dateObj.selectedDay)
            console.log(dateObj);

           //You can see the result of the date in string that way
           $('.string').append(dateText);

           currDate = new Date(dateText);
           //You can have a complete Date object using the Date javascript method
           console.log(currDate);

           //The Date object in javascript provides you all you need then

          //Get the number of day in a week, from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
          $('.getday').append(currDate.getDay());

         //Create a function to see day Sun - Sat
         function getWeekDay(date) {
           var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat']
           return days[ date.getDay() ]
         } 
         //Then we use it
         $('.getweekday').append(getWeekDay(currDate));
    }
   });
 });
```

You can see my fiddle there:
https://jsfiddle.net/qapw32Lp/

Here is a great source of information you can use also abotu the Date Object:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions